# Grails Delete bi-directional one-to-one association

Tags: grails, associations, grails-orm

I have two domain classes with bidirectional one to one association:

**Domains**

```
class Nose {

  String str1

  static belongsTo = [face:Face]

}
```

---

```
class Face {

  String str1

  static hasOne = [nose: Nose]

}
```

**Controllers**

```
class NoseController {
  def create() {
    nose.properties = params
    nose.save(flush: true)
  }

  def delete() {
    def nose = Nose.get(params.id as long)
    nose.delete(flush: true)
  }
}
```

---

```
class FaceController {

   def create() {
      def face = new Face()        
      def nose = Nose.get(params.id as long)

      if(!nose){
         face.nose = nose
         face.properties = params
         face.save(flush: true)

         nose.face = face
         nose.properties = params
         nose.save(flush:true)
      }else{
         face.properties = params
         face.save(flush: true)
      }
   }

   def delete() {
      def face = Face.get(params.id as long)
      face.delete(flush: true)
   }
}
```

After creating **Nose** and **Face** objects, I can't **delete** and **update** them.
When I want to delete Face I get exception:

> org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Foreign key
>   constraint violation trying to delete teastrelation.Face with id 1 at
>   org.grails.hbase.gorm.DeletePersistentMethod.invoke(DeletePersistentMethod.groovy:66)
>     at org.grails.hbase.gorm.PersistentMethod$invoke.call(Unknown Source)
>     at org.grails.hbase.gorm.PersistentMethod$invoke.call(Unknown Source)

For removing in FaceController I have changed remove action:

```
def delete() {
    def face = Face.get(params.id as long)
    def nose = Nose.get(face.nose.id)

    face.nose = null
    nose.face = null
    nose.save(flush:true)
    face.save(flush:true)
    face.delete(flush: true)

    render params.id

}
```

and only after it I can delete **Face** object, but it throw the following exception:

> ERROR gorm.SavePersistentMethod  - Cannot get property 'class' on null
>   object java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'class' on
>   null object   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.getProperty(NullObject.java:56)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getProperty(InvokerHelper.java:156)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassGetPropertySite.callGetProperty(PojoMetaClassGetPropertySite.java:41)

When i want to update Face object, i got the following exception:

> ERROR associations.ReferenceTable  - Reference table entry not found,
>   row=[79, 78, 69, 84, 79, 79, 78, 69, 95, 79, 78, 69, 84, 79, 79, 78,
>   69, 95, 68, 79, 77, 65, 73, 78, 50, 95, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
>
> ERROR gorm.SavePersistentMethod  -Cannot get property 'class' on null
>   object java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'class' on
>   null object
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.getProperty(NullObject.java:56)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getProperty(InvokerHelper.java:156)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassGetPropertySite.callGetProperty(PojoMetaClassGetPropertySite.java:41)

I use grails 1.3.2 and hbase-0.2.4 plugin and I can not use mapping..

What am I doing wrong ?

I have already spent a lot of time on this problem.. please help if anyone can.

Answer (score 1):

I created a simple application to model your issue.  In my example, I followed best practices, namely writing a service to manage the objects and some tests.  As a note, the create method on your Domain1Controller calls `save(flush:true)` 3 times (twice on d1 and once on d2), which is probably not good and might be your issue.

Here is what I did

domain class 1:

```
package com.example

class Owner {
    String example;
    static constraints = {
        friend unique:true
    }
    static hasOne = [friend: Owned]
}
```

domain class 2

```
package com.example

class Owned {

    String name;
    static constraints = {
    }
    static belongsTo = [owner: Owner]
}
```

service to manage those domain classes

```
package com.example

class OwnerService {

    static transactional = true

    def saveNewOwnerAndOwned(ownerField, ownedField){
        def owner = new Owner(example: ownedField)
        def owned = new Owned(name: ownedField)

        owner.friend = owned
        // since the relationship is bidirectional, need to set up
        // the references both ways
        owned.owner = owner

        owner.save(flush: true)
        return owner
    }

    def deleteOwner(id) {

        def toDelete = Owner.get(id)
        toDelete.delete(flush:true)

    }

    def deleteOwnedOfOwner(ownerId) {
        def owner = Owner.get(ownerId)
        def owned = owner.friend

        // must break the relationship
        owner.friend = null

        owned.delete(flush: true);
    }     
}
```

tests to make sure its working

```
package com.example

class OwnerServiceIntegrationTests extends GroovyTestCase {

    def ownerService
    def sessionFactory

    public void testSave(){
        def owner = ownerService.saveNewOwnerAndOwned("im an owner", "im owned");

        assertNotNull(owner)
        assertNotNull(owner.id)
        assertNotNull(owner.friend)
        assertNotNull(owner.friend.id)
    }

    public void testDelete() {

        def owner = ownerService.saveNewOwnerAndOwned("im an owner", "im owned");
        def id = owner.id
        def ownedId = owner.friend.id
        ownerService.deleteOwner(id);

        // since the integration tests hit an actual db
        // clear the session so when i start testing im sure its accurate
        def session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
        session.clear()

        // make sure everything was deleted, i.e. not in db
        assertNull(Owner.get(id))
        assertNull(Owned.get(ownedId))
    }

    public void testDeleteOwned() {
        def owner = ownerService.saveNewOwnerAndOwned("im an owner", "im owned");
        def id = owner.id

        ownerService.deleteOwnedOfOwner(id);

        def session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
        session.clear()

        owner = Owner.get(id)
        // make sure owner still there but friend is not
        assertNotNull(owner)
        assertNull(owner.friend)
    }


}
```

Comment: in this case we have not got bidirectin asscciation, have we? Because owned=null (it has not been saved). For bidirectional association in create method I wrote the following code:                 def owned = new Owned(name:ownedField)                              owned.save(flush: true)
def owner = new Owner(example: ownedField)
owner.friend = owned
owner.save(flush: true)
owned.owner = owner owned.save(flush:true)                                               After it I have tried delete them with methods, but I got exception. If your try again, please post your result..

Comment: yes you do.  You have belongsTo and hasOne (with fields pointing to each other)--- thats bidirectional.  If you do not want bidirectional, then take out the child 'owned' class's reference to its parent and it will be unidirectional.

Comment: no, I want them to be bidirectional... I mean, in this example if write:  owner.friend = owned
        owned.owner = owner
        owner.save(flush: true)
and save owner and do not save owned, it will not be bidirectional. To make it bidirectional, I have to call svae(flush: true)  method 3 times..

Comment: @bella, no you don't.  Bidirectional has to do with the mapping.  The mapping informs how you save them.  Look at my example.  My domain objects are the same as yours.  Look in my service at saveNewOwnerAndOwned.  I the fact that each object points to the other implies the bidirectionality.  Look in the method, one save.  Look in the test, after the save, both objects are persisted.

Comment: @hvgotcodes i am debugging saveNewOwnerAndOwned method. In db saves only owner. It does not save owned with owner..

Comment: @bella yes it does.  look at the test.  if it didnt save the owned, then owner.friend.id would be null.

Comment: @hvgotcodes Have you tried test saving with debug? ...maybe it does not save in my application..